# How to reuse slim.arg_scope in tensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load `inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt` file and do testing.

The code works well with single image (entering oneFile() function only once).

If I call oneFile() function twice, the following error occur:

> ValueError: Variable InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights already
>   exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
>   Originally defined at:

I found related solution on [Sharing Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/variable_scope/)

If `tf.variable_scope` meet the same problem, could call `scope.reuse_variables()` to resolve this problem.

But I can't find the `slim.arg_scope` version to reuse the scope.

```
def oneFile(filepath):
imgPath = filepath
testImage_string = tf.gfile.FastGFile(imgPath, 'rb').read()
testImage = tf.image.decode_jpeg(testImage_string, channels=3)
processed_image = inception_preprocessing.preprocess_image(testImage, image_size, image_size, is_training=False)
processed_images = tf.expand_dims(processed_image, 0)


# Create the model, use the default arg scope to configure the batch norm parameters.
with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
    #logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(images, num_classes = dataset.num_classes, is_training = False)
    logits, _ = inception_resnet_v2(processed_images, num_classes=16, is_training=False)

probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
    checkpoint_file,
    slim.get_model_variables(model_name))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_fn(sess)

    np_image, probabilities = sess.run([processed_images, probabilities])
    probabilities = probabilities[0, 0:]
    sorted_inds = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(-probabilities), key=lambda x: x[1])]
    #print(probabilities)
    print(probabilities.argmax(axis=0))
    #names = imagenet.create_readable_names_for_imagenet_labels()
    #for i in range(15):
    #    index = sorted_inds[i]
    #    print((probabilities[index], names[index]))

def main():
for image_file in os.listdir(dataset_dir):
    try:
        image_type = imghdr.what(os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_file))
        if not image_type:
            continue
    except IsADirectoryError:
        continue

    #image = Image.open(os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_file))
    filepath = os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_file)

    oneFile(filepath)
```

inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope

```
def inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope(weight_decay=0.00004,
                                  batch_norm_decay=0.9997,
                                  batch_norm_epsilon=0.001):
  """Yields the scope with the default parameters for inception_resnet_v2.

  Args:
    weight_decay: the weight decay for weights variables.
    batch_norm_decay: decay for the moving average of batch_norm momentums.
    batch_norm_epsilon: small float added to variance to avoid dividing by zero.

  Returns:
    a arg_scope with the parameters needed for inception_resnet_v2.
  """
  # Set weight_decay for weights in conv2d and fully_connected layers.
  with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                      weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(weight_decay),
                      biases_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)):

    batch_norm_params = {
        'decay': batch_norm_decay,
        'epsilon': batch_norm_epsilon,
    }
    # Set activation_fn and parameters for batch_norm.
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d], activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                        normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
                        normalizer_params=batch_norm_params) as scope:

      return scope
```

Complete error message:

> ./data/test/teeth/1/7070.jpg Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "testing.py", line 111, in 
>       main()   File "testing.py", line 106, in main
>       cal(processed_images)   File "testing.py", line 67, in cal
>       logits, _ = inception_resnet_v2(processed_images, num_classes=16, is_training=False)   File
>   "/notebooks/transfer_learning_tutorial/inception_resnet_v2.py", line
>   123, in inception_resnet_v2
>       scope='Conv2d_1a_3x3')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 918, in convolution
>       outputs = layer.apply(inputs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
>   line 320, in apply
>       return self.**call**(inputs, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
>   line 286, in **call**
>       self.build(input_shapes[0])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py",
>   line 138, in build
>       dtype=self.dtype)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 1049, in get_variable
>       use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 948, in get_variable
>       use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 349, in get_variable
>       validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 1389, in wrapped_custom_getter
>       *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
>   line 275, in variable_getter
>       variable_getter=functools.partial(getter, **kwargs))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
>   line 228, in _add_variable
>       trainable=trainable and self.trainable)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 1334, in layer_variable_getter
>       return _model_variable_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 1326, in _model_variable_getter
>       custom_getter=getter, use_resource=use_resource)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 262, in model_variable
>       use_resource=use_resource)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 217, in variable
>       use_resource=use_resource)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 341, in _true_getter
>       use_resource=use_resource)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 653, in _get_single_variable
>       name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb)))) ValueError: Variable InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights already exists, disallowed.
>   Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 217, in variable
>       use_resource=use_resource)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 262, in model_variable
>       use_resource=use_resource)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `tf.reset_default_graph()` before processing each image in your `oneFile()` function will solve this problem, as I encountered the same issue on a very similar example code. My understanding is that once you feed the image to the neural network (NN), because of the *variable scope* concept TensorFlow uses, it needs to be told that the variables can be reused before you can apply the NN to another image.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you specified the same scope for multiple variables in the graph. This error occurs when tensorflow finds multiple variables under the same scope which is irrespective of the next image or the next batch. When you create the graph, you should create it thinking about one image or batch only. If everything works well with the first batch or first image, tensorflow will take care of the next iterations including the scoping.

So check all the scopes in your model file. I am pretty sure you used the same name twice.